# Build image with a Dockerfile - unknown instruction

Tags: image, powershell, docker, dockerfile

I'm following this tutorial: https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockerimages/#building-an-image-from-a-dockerfile

And now I'm launching the command:`docker build -t ouruser/sinatra:v2 .`

This is the output:[image]

I've created the Dockerfile with the `$null > filename` command and then with notepad I've inserted into it the code suggested by the tutorial.

Am I missing something ?

---

Dockerfile[image]

It's a ctrl+c and ctrl+v from the tutorial.

Comment: show us your dockerfile

Comment: Post the Dockerfile, it seems you have some characters to remove

Comment: Open your dockerfile in Notepad++ and check what is the encoding used (menu "Encoding").

Comment: If the solution above didn't work´, try to change your "new line charachter" of your Dockerfile to EOL linux mode using notepad ++ in edit menu. that night help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just copypasted it from the example, it works fine, try copypasting from here, you probably pasted some extra characters. Also set encoding to UTF-8.

```
# This is a comment
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Kate Smith <ksmith@example.com>
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ruby ruby-dev
RUN gem install sinatra
```

update, as Mohammed Noureldin pointed out, if that didn't work try fixing your EOL characters.

Comment: Thanks it was the encoding to another format that caused the problem.
Thanks again.

Comment: oh, ok, if that answer fixes your problem you should mark it as solved ;) thanks ;)